# how to resolve invalid action in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

[image]

```
core.js:1671 ERROR Error: Effect "AuthEffect.login$" dispatched an invalid action: undefined
    at reportInvalidActions (effects.js:219)
    at verifyOutput (effects.js:207)
    at MapSubscriber.project (effects.js:273)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
```

I am getting below error when I hit to my service using `ngrx` .here is my code

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthEffect {
  @Effect()
  login$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActionsTypes.LOGIN),
    map((action: Login) => action.payload),
    switchMap((auth: Authenticate) => {
      return this.authService.login(auth).pipe(
        map(user => this.store.dispatch(new LoginSuccess({user}))),
        catchError(error => of(new LoginFailure(error)))
      );
    })
  );
```

an issue on this line when I used `this.store` it's gives me error , if I used

```
  map(user => this.store.dispatch(new LoginSuccess({user}))),
```

if I used `new LoginSuccess({user})` it works fine .why i am not able to dispatch 
`action` from here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do the dispatching yourself.
Every action "returned" from an effect will be dispatched by @ngrx/effects.

```
map(user => new LoginSuccess({user}))
```

On a side note, if you are not dispatching actions you have to use

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false})
```

If you add the `dispatch: false` to the effect your snippet should also work, but it's better to just return the action instead of dispatching it yourself.